# Can you implement a "select all" checkbox in HTML without JavaScript?

Tags: html, checkbox

I'm looking for a clean way to implement the infamous "select all" checkbox, but I'd prefer a JavaScript-free solution. Does anyone know if there is a way to do that?

Thank you in advance

Comment: Do you mean clicking a 'check all' check box that automatically checks other check boxes on the page?  I don't think that is possible without javascript.

Comment: I think it is impossible. This process changing DOM, HTML cannot do this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

While it is possible to achieve part of this functionality without the use of JavaScript, I wouldn’t recommend it as it doesn’t work in older browsers.

You could use the CSS3 `:target` pseudo-class to toggle between different `<form>`s in your markup. Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/mathias/kFH3e/

As you can see, it doesn’t really “toggle” the checkboxes, but just the forms; and if you’ve already checked some boxes in one of the form it will still be checked after you switch back and forth.

This is one of the cases where it’s perfectly acceptable to use JavaScript, as the “select all/none” buttons only enhance the UI; it’s still an acceptable experience without them.

TL;DR It’s okay to use JavaScript in this case.

Comment: “While it is possible to achieve this effect without the use of JavaScript” — Is it? How?

Comment: @PaulD.Waite Updated my post; added a link to a demo. As I mentioned, this is not a very good idea. This is one of the cases where it’s perfectly acceptable to use JavaScript, as it _enhances_ the UI, and it’s still an acceptable experience without the “select all/none” buttons.

Comment: @Mathias: ah, I see, that’s a really clever idea. Doesn’t quite achieve the functionality, and it’d be a bit confusing if CSS was turned off, but I like the inventive thinking.

Comment: This could be confusing and would only work if the form was just checkboxs. If any text fields are part of the form it will not work properly, since you cannot copy fields from one form to another without a DOM Manipulator like javascript.

Answer (score 4):

Unfortunately there is no way to select all checkboxes without some scripting. HTML is a static language and cannot manipulate itself in any way without a request being sent. You will need to implement javascript to utilize a select all box. you can use one of the following two:

### JQUERY

```
 <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.2/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
 function toggleChecked(status) {
  $(".checkbox").each( function() { // if checkboxs have class
   $(this).attr("checked",status);
  })
 }
```

### Javascript

```
 function selectToggle(toggle, form) {
  var myForm = document.forms[form];
      for( var i=0; i < myForm.length; i++ ) { 
          if(toggle) {
              myForm.elements[i].checked = "checked";
         } 
          else {
              myForm.elements[i].checked = "";
          }
      }
 }
```

Comment: thanks for the javascript code, although I didn't ask for it.

Comment: I know you did not ask for it but added just in case and for people searching the questions so they can find it and use it.

Answer (score 3):

### client-side solution

Need to use javascript to when a checkbox checked check rest

### server-side solution

Need to **reload** page

when a link clicked reload page with all checkbox tags checked in php

Example for server-side solution

```
if (isset($_GET['selectall'](){
    $check_status = " checked";
else {
    $check_status = "";
}


for ($i=0;$i<100;$i++){
    /* Line Codes */
    print "<input  type=\"checkbox\" name="\checkname\" $check_status>";
    /* Rest Codes */
}
```